# ng5-slider - How can we change background-color of slider-active?

Tags: css, angular

I would like to change the background-color of the active pointer ?

[image: Default background-color is #451AFF]

In Chrome's inspector I can change it, the class is :

```
.ng5-slider-active::after { background-color: #451AFF; }
```

But I can't do the same in my **css file**.

I tried this but that doesn't seem to work :

```
::ngdeep {
  .custom-slider .ng5-slider .ng5-slider-pointer .ng5-slider-active::after {
    background-color: #fff!important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finaly found it, if it can help someone

```
::ngdeep {
  .custom-slider .ng5-slider-active::after {
    background-color: #fff!important;
  }
}
```